# Assign a void* variable to a struct variable

Tags: c, sockets, struct, void-pointers

I have a void* variable which I am getting through a socket connection. I need to cast this to a struct type, wich is defined both on the client and server side.

I have provided a sample of the assignment in question in the code below. In the example I am leaving out the networking code  for the sake of briefness.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct
{
    int x;
    int y;
} testStructType;


void someFunction(void* p)
{
    //some processing goes here.


}


int main(void) {

    testStructType testStruct;
    void* p;

    p=malloc(sizeof(testStructType));

    someFunction(p);


    testStruct=p;


    printf("%i ,%i",testStruct.x,testStruct.y);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The problem is that I get error
incompatible types when assigning to type 'testStructType' from 'void*'

What am I doing wrong?
Can somebody please help me?

Comment: The assignment `testStruct=p` will fail, because `testStruct` is a structure, and `p` is a generic pointer. Actually, you probably don't need to use generic pointers (i.e. `void *`) at all. Just use pointers to the structure, and try to use that as much as you can. Many socket receive/send functions wants `char *` for data, but then just cast the pointer to the structure when needed. If a function expects a generic pointer, then no casting is needed at all.

Comment: `testStruct=p;` : Different type as `(testStructType) = (void*)`, change to `testStruct=*(testStructType *)p;`

Comment: And, of course, the program at both ends of the socket should be compiled using the same version of the same compiler, invoked with the same flags, and running on the same OS. It only takes a little change to make the structs at each end incompatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean

```
testStruct = *(testStructType *)p;
```

To get at the contents of what a pointer points at, you need to *dereference* it.

This makes a copy of the struct. If you don't actually need a copy then you can access the original directly:

```
testStructType *pt = p;
printf("%i ,%i", pt->x, pt->y);
```

Note that you are not "getting a void* variable through a socket connection". You are getting some data through a socket connection, and the void* variable is pointing at that data.

Answer (score 0):

It's a pointer, so the line that reads

```
    testStructType testStruct;
```

should read

```
    testStructType *testStruct;
```

then the following code needs to change to:

```
    testStruct = (testStructType *)p;

    printf("%d, %d", testStruct->x, testStruct->y);
```

Comment: i ttyed that solution as well but it still gave me an error. @Matt McNabb proposed solution did the trick for me. Thank you anyway for your support.

Comment: If `p` is of type `void*`, then the cast is not necessary.

Comment: @alk While technically that's true, most good compilers will generate a warning if you try to assign from a void pointer to a non-void pointer without an appropriate cast.  It's good practice to cast.

Comment: @alastair: Would you mind giving any examples for C compilers doing so?

Comment: @alk Well, first off, if you're using C++ rather than C, it's an outright error.  If you're using a C compiler, there's usually a warning option you can turn on for this; for instance, GCC has `-Wc++-compat`.

Comment: So, as this question is about C, it might be worth mentioning that **not** casting void-pointers 100%ly confomrs the C-Standard.